# Is weight pruning applied to all layers or only to dense layers in CNNs?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I was reading about weight pruning in convolutional neural networks. Is it applied for all the layers including convolutional layers or only it is done for dense layers?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community. Where were you reading about weight pruning?